# What would it take to have NXP and CO produce matched transistors in a DIP6 package?

Tags: transistors

What would it take to have NXP and CO produce matched transistors, like BCM847 & BCM857 in a DIP6 package?

The SOT 23-6 is so small, pretty to hard to solder with a hobby soldering station that has a 0.05 inch wide point.

edit: i found a substitutes:
NSS40302
NSS40301
NSS40300

Witch are SOIC8 and available again after a chip shortage.

Comment: A couple of barrels of (twenty) dollar bills ought to do it.

Comment: Just solder the flippin' things.  SOT-23-6 can easily be done by hand.  I use an iron with a 1mm tip and have no trouble with parts that size (and smaller.)

Comment: A hell of a lot of money. I'm sure they'll do it if you pay them enough, but "enough" would likely be on the order of $1M or so. Far cheaper to practice soldering and/or get a more suitable soldering station.

Comment: @JRE, they could use the same silicon part, but use a different package.
i'm aware i could use solder wick to remove to excess.

Comment: @NaturalDemon You underestimate how difficult it is to package up semiconductors. You're right, using existing dice would drop the price from millions to a hundred thousand or so, but it would still be a major undertaking. Not something they'll do just because you asked; something they'll do because you asked and agreed to buy a few million parts.

Comment: It's not like there's a guy in the back room, stuffing little pieces of silicon into little black housings, one by one, on demand.  When they do it, they do it by the righteous boatload - tens of thousands to millions on a production line made for high volume.

Comment: Then, too, that's just your one part covered.  What about the other parts in your circuit?  All the op-amps in SOIC, or the single transistors in SOT?  You'll still have to handle them.

Comment: **If** NXP would answer you (and they won't, I know, I've worked there, they're not interested in small customers) then they would refer you to **Nexperia** (split-off from NXP) as that is now the manufacturer of discrete transistors. Also Nexperia will not talk to you. I know, I'm a consultant there, they're only interested in very large customers.

Comment: @JRE the SOT23-3 has bigger leads looks a lot more manageable with a soldering iron, you can see the pins against a SOT 23-6 or SOT23-5, there also exists SOT23-8, but that would be a challenge if you have a design that's really good, passed the stage of prototyping and outsource the population of the boards. i could mount the SOT23-6 on a DIP8 sized PCB and stick it on the back, but than it's almost as big at 2 regulator transistors.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yeah, i know, they told me contact NEXPERIA and i did get a reply, they refused, but still the parts appeared on the market later on. a year or so later when i accidentally fell over them. ( Mini Logic packages ), have a single CD4013 on a chip instead of 2.

Comment: Matched transistors in a single package exist, go look for them on mouser etc. There are few of these and that's because they're only needed in special applications. These days, almost everyone would simply use an **opamp**. You might want to explain **why** you need matched transistors in a new question where you ask for an alternative design solution.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Exponential converter for synthesizer, current mirrors for a VCA.
i know the Renesas HAF3046/HAf3096 exist, but they are very very expensive. 8€ and upwards.

Comment: *but they are very very expensive* Yeah, because they're only for niche applications, almost no one needs them. I'm thinking small SMD BJTs mounted close together would be "good enough" but difficult to solder (use hot air soldering!). Alternative: 2 through-hole transistors in a **metal** can (BC108?) or just TO92 plastic housing and thermally couple them. Also consider adding a small **emitter resistor** to even out some mismatch. There's also this one-NPN logamp: https://www.electronicshub.org/operational-amplifier-applications/

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, yeah, i could epoxy them together, but than i have to match them manually, testing some 100 transistors. 

https://web.archive.org/web/20151002134800/http://home.comcast.net/~ijfritz/MiscProj/transmat001.pdf + the cost of that PCB, switches, precision resistors.

Comment: *i have to match them manually, testing some 100 transistors* It all depends on how "good" your matching needs to be. If you can allow 10% mismatch, a couple of emitter resistors might be you need for a current mirror. For 1% matching: just drop more voltage across the emitter resistors. I would try to **design** the circuit such that the mismatch is not an issue, if that's not possible, I would consider **calibration**. Matched components is the last thing I would consider as that gives all the issues you now have.

Comment: @Theodore, maybe some day i have the change and resources to approach manufacturer, i  have found one that also makes pcb and populates them for the fastest and most powerful electric cars on the planet. i just wanna know the result before, i do have BCM847 and BCM857  here, it's just a bit scary i fail on that part and have to trow away an entire pcb.

Comment: ::Boggle::  If you mess up soldering your BCM847 or BCM857, then you just **remove** them from the board and try again.  They are as easy to remove as they are to solder.  Easier, even.

Comment: @JRE, mounting and removing is easy, agree, just worried to have a short circuit and not seeing. still wished that they (NXP, Nexperia, Texas Instruments and co) also have DIY'ers, prototyper, hobbyist in mind. i'm sure they would sell at least 10.000 if not more of matched transistors around the globe to these people.

Comment: @JRE even SOIC format was better than SOT23-6

Comment: I **am** a DIYer and hobbyist.  I'd take the SOT-23-6 over the DIP6 any day.  SMD is **worlds** easier to handle, solder, and remove.  I only use a plain, standard soldering iron.  No reflow oven or hot air tools.  Works fine, no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things that come to mind that would be certainly cheaper and easier:

- Buying a reflow oven or fine tip soldering iron. Doesn't need to be super fancy or top of the line, but should at least be decent quality. SOT-23-6 is not a terribly difficult package as long as you have decent equipment and a decent footprint on your PCB.
- Getting a PCBA manufacturer (or a friend with good equipment) to fabricate breakout boards with the part and some headers populated. If you absolutely need a DIP for prototyping, this is a simple way of using one or two surface mount parts in an otherwise through-hole design. The breakout boards themselves are fairly cheap, but a PCBA assembler may have requirements like panelization or a minimum order quantity.
- Having your whole design made by a PCBA fabricator. You would send Gerber files and pick and place instructions and they would do assembly of the whole board. For this case, committing to SMT throughout may actually *save* costs because of the ease with which surface mount parts can be picked and placed with automated equipment. Since you're using SOT-23-6 packages and not something extremely difficult like WL-CSP, you don't need the most advanced assembly capabilities and almost any surface mount assembly service should suffice.